# Is it possible to change font for Itextsharp List?

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, itext

I've got ItextSharp list and i need to change whole list font, because i'am from Czech Republic and we have special characters (ěč and other...) and basic font doesn't support that characters. I have already created some mine fonts for Paragraph

```
       string font = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "arialbd.ttf");

BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(font, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

            Font BoldE = new Font(baseFont, 30);
```

and i used it like : Paragraph Example = new Paragraph("Some text here", BoldE);

But i don't know about Lists. I tryed some things, but not worked for me.

Comment: `ListItem` extends `Paragraph`, so whatever works for `Paragraph` works for `ListItem`. Show us how you tried to define the font of a `ListItem` instead of saying *"I tried some things, but I couldn't make it work."*

Comment: I didn't work with ListItem.

Comment: Why not? Didn't you read the documentation? If not, why not? How can you try "some things" if you don't read the [documentation](http://developers.itextpdf.com)? That's really weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at the [ListWithLeading](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-building-blocks/list-examples#1288-listwithleading.java) example. In this example, we create a `List` using different `ListItem` objects. We create a `Font` for each item:

```
Font font = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12); 
List list1 = new List(12); 
list1.add(new ListItem("Value 1", font)); 
list1.add(new ListItem("Value 2", font)); 
 list1.add(new ListItem("Value 3", font)); 
 document.add(list1);
```

The `ListItem` class extends the `Paragraph` class, so whatever works for you with paragraphs will also work with list items.

Comment: Okay, thank you :) i will read more things about ItextSharp. It is something new for me.